# How does numpy.dot work for 1-d array and multi-dimensional array?

Tags: python, numpy

Specifically, why does the following not work

```
a = np.array([[3],[2],[1],[2]])
b = np.array([1, 2, 5, 2])
np.dot(b,a)
```

It gives error:

```
ValueError: shapes (4,1) and (4,) not aligned: 1 (dim 1) != 4 (dim 0)
```

But this works:

```
np.dot(a,b)
```

Comment: This is because your arrays have different shapes. Your `a` array has a shape of `(4,1)` and your `b` array has shape `(4,)`

Comment: @DavidG How does switching a and b in the argument to np.dot make their shapes compatible?

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> b=b.reshape(1,4)    #just reshape b
>>> b
array([[1, 2, 5, 2]])
>>> a
array([[3],
       [2],
       [1],
       [2]])

>>> np.dot(a,b)
array([[ 3,  6, 15,  6],
       [ 2,  4, 10,  4],
       [ 1,  2,  5,  2],
       [ 2,  4, 10,  4]])
>>> np.dot(b,a)
array([[16]])
```

Comment: You could also have made this assignment `b.shape = (1, 4)` instead of calling the method `reshape()`